# How to get near by places in iOS Watch

Tags: ios, location, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I have started to work with apple watch recently. Now, I am facing problems on getting nearby places. We can get near by places from mobile apps using GooglePlaces.Framework but I can't integrate it to the watch app.

Please help me about it. I have been struggling since one week. Is there any solution for it?